# Is the Signal Flare a gun?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

We played Last Night On Earth yesterday and got a little confused as to whether or not the Signal Flare was a gun.

I had Father Joseph in the Gun Shop and I thought that the Signal Flare was a gun (it looks like a gun, you fire it) which meant that I could pick it up but not use it. My opponent thought it was not a gun which meant I'd have to go to the Airplane Hanger to pick it up, but Father Joseph could use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last Night on Earth guns should say "Item - Ranged Weapon - Gun" beneath the picture, and also  have a little red icon of a gun in the top right corner of the text box.

I don't have the card to hand, but my understanding of Signal Flare is that it doesn't conform to the above and isn't a gun (despite the obvious superficial similarities).

It seems a bit strange that a priest would have moral compunctions about using a signal flare in any case!